# Was the rescue in Episode 6 "Beyond the Wall" achieved in a plausible time?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In Episode 6 of Season 7 of *Game of Thrones* ("Beyond the Wall") Jon and the group that went beyond the Wall to bring back a wight to King's Landing find themselves surrounded by the Army of the Dead. Just before this happens, Jon asks Gendry to travel to the Eastwatch-by-the-Sea and send ravens to Dany in Dragonstone to help them out beyond the Wall.

Even if the TV show is running the time a bit faster episode-wise it would still take a bit of time for:

1. Gendry to travel back to the Wall.
2. A raven to get from the Wall to Dragonstone.
3. Dany riding off to beyond the Wall to help Jon and company.

Given there's a lot of geographical distance at play here, how much time passed between Gendry splitting from the group and Dany getting to them?

Comment: Related, Possible dupe: [How long does it take for a Dragon to fly North of the Wall?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166108/54887)

Comment: Books canon answer can still be used even if there is only GoT tag, as distance and travel can be same for both books and tv show (even if in the tv show they seem to teleport a lot), but as the situation i specific to the tv-show, only GoT tag should be used

Comment: @Kepotx The distance and travel is indeed the same....That is to say deliberately vague. It's by Design.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64202/discussion-on-question-by-drag0nkn1ght-was-daenerys-rescue-achieved-in-a-plausi).

Comment: @Zaibis, regarding your diatribe in the edit comment: "Beyond the Wall" is **the name of the episode**. The tile as it is now is vague to be point of meaningless. It could apply to any of thousands of stories.

Comment: [The director of the episode admits it didn't quite work](http://io9.gizmodo.com/the-people-behind-game-of-thrones-admit-this-weeks-resc-1798304996)

Comment: @JoshCaswell: In that case I would advice just writing episode 6 season 7. If thats that important.

Comment: Season 7 _of what_? How is it less spoiley to number the episode than to name it?

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Well I got your point that its not spily. But as I'm not there yet, how could I know thats the episodes name. So my point was isntead one should just wrote in the episode he is refering to, isntead its title, which could also be refering to a in universe place. NVM, I'm out.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

A [user on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/mikeCFNI) did some calculations claiming it was accurate. The user estimated it to be around 5 days based on growth rate of ice, the air speed of an <s>unladen swallow</s> raven, and approximation for distances and dragon speed.

<sub>[Link to the original post](https://www.reddit.com/r/gameofthrones/comments/6uzztg/s7e6_gendry_and_the_ravens_isnt_teleportation/)</sub>

I've broken down their answer but provided a link to the original just above.

- Gendry's run, around 4 hours:

  - The Seven (/Twelve with the additional rangers) likely weren't travelling in a line straight north. They were searching for the Army of the dead, and specifically a lone wight or, as they ended up finding, a small party of wights. This means they would likely be travelling in a zig-zag type of walk to cover as much area as possible. Furthermore sticking to higher altitude so they would have that over their opponents (As they end up looking down at the wights in the canyon).
  - Gendry running at full speed would require about 4 hours to cover a significant amount of ground. We can't be sure how many days the Seven had been travelling for, but if we assume it to be about 2 days of zigzagging over quite a large area it would be a reasonable assumption for it to take Gendry about 4 hours to run back.
- The Raven likely took around 3 days to get from Eastwatch to Dragonstone.

  - A raven flying from Eastwatch to Winterfell would be about a day:
    Homing pigeons have been recorded to be able to reach speeds of up to 50mph and although [discussions have taken place](http://asoiaf.westeros.org/index.php?/topic/91120-how-far-can-ravens-fly-in-a-day/) to the speed of ravens, although no real speed is given, we are led to believe that in-universe ravens are quicker and stronger that in-universe pigeons as stated by Maester Aemon:

    > Doves and pigeons can also be trained to carry messages,” the maester [Aemon] went on, “though the raven is a stronger flyer, larger, bolder, far more clever, better able to defend itself against hawks ...
  - Continuing this idea to flying to Dragonstone. It's about the same distance from Winterfell to Kings Landing as it is to Dragonstone. The show claims it to be about 1000 miles from Winterfell to King's Landing (according to the user). This gives us about 3 days of raven flight if we take the 500 mile per day cap set by the users in the discussion above.
- Dany and her dragons likely took around 8 or so hours to fly to "Snow team 6"

  - The user approximated around 125mph for a Dragon with a rider. Given the size of the Dragons, this seem possible as a normal hawk is able to fly around 70mph. Whether wingspan changes speed is unclear but big birds tend to be quicker than small birds.

This gives us about 5 days of total travel from Gendry running to the Dragons arriving.

The ice aspect is a bit strange. As 10˚F is around -12˚C and doesn't seem that cold for Gendry to be crying about the freezing cold weather. It was likely closer to -30˚C to -40˚C which I guess would make the ice freeze twice as quick. But bearing in mind that the Ice was thin in the first place there might be something that was preventing the water from garnering thickness very quickly. Such as the hot springs which exist naturally in the north (Winterfell's walls, Ygritte and Jon's cave) may have slowed the freezing of the water.

---

#### There are theories it can be done in ~3 days.

If we take the 500 miles per day, and the fact that white Ravens can fly from Old Town to Winterfell, it's possible a Raven can fly to Dragonstone from Eastwatch directly. This would cut down travel time to about 2 days of raven flight (at 50mph with rest). If we take a Dragons airspeed to be around 200mph it would do the return flight in 5 hours. Easily done in ~three days, allowing for better calculation for the rate of freezing of the water.

Comment: "As 10˚F is around -12˚C and doesn't seem that cold for Gendry to be crying about the freezing cold weather" - 10 degrees F is pretty cold.  If the ice was insufficiently frozen at the beginning, it was either a high salinity, the water was warmer than the air, or the initial temperatures were warmer. I live in the northern US.  People from the south complain about how cold it is before temperatures ever drop below freezing (32 F or 0 C). Gendry said he'd never even seen snow before.  Part of the ribbing he was taking was for complaining while it was still relatively mild.

Comment: 10F is really not that cold. That's personal opinion, but I'd happily wager a northerner wouldn't be that cold at 10F I've worn shorts in that weather. In snow, not a problem

Comment: Gendry is from King's Landing, which has a warm climate.

Comment: Jon survived the same trip as Gendry did in the same temperature with wet clothes without moving on horseback. [A random webpage found by Google](http://www.seagrant.umn.edu/coastal_communities/hypothermia) suggests that humans may survive 45 minutes in 0.3 °C water. So if the horse took around that time to reach the Wall, it would give the correct order of magnitude. Jon is a badass with both Northern blood and fire in his veins, so he might survive longer in cold.

Comment: Lengthy comment discussion about ice has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64207/discussion-on-answer-by-edlothiad-was-daenerys-rescue-achieved-in-a-plausible-t). Please continue that conversation there, and use further comments here only for constructive things about this answer.

Comment: I don't think a human could survive in the north, above the clouds, and traveling at 125 mph. 10°F@15k feet will feel about -40. Add 125mph wind chill factor and it would feel like -125°F. For 8 hours.

Comment: @Shane when you explain how Dragons exist I'll explain how that's possible.

Comment: This answer is fine if we suppose that Jon Snow & friends were stranded for days on end on the lake. If they were, shouldn't there have been dialogue or a montage or something clueing us in that time is passing? My first impression is that they spent one night out on the ice & were rescued on the 2nd day.

Comment: @Shane Presumable the dragon was awfully warn though.

Comment: @RobertF they've done a lot of timeskips this season and in the past. I personally think it would be terribly boring to watch a montage of some people say on an island after they've sent someone on a marathon run and scrambled their jets. You've just gone from 0 to 60 and then suggest turning the pace back down to 0? That would've ruined the episode in my opinion. You're impression would also mean that Dany knew to rescue them without the raven

Comment: I like your names for Jon's party. I've been referring to them as the Merry Men (good guy outlaws) because I couldn't think of anything else.

Comment: @Edlothiad A montage could be boring, you need snappy rock music to tie it all together. :) So then some dialogue, like the Hound complaining "We've been freezing our balls off for three f*****g days!" or some dissension in the ranks. Dany did know they were heading up to Eastwatch & then north from there, conceivably she could have spent a few hours aloft searching for them. And she had three pairs of eyes looking for them.

Comment: @MatthewRead I had that thought too. Do they ever mention anywhere that dragons are markedly warm to the touch?

Comment: @Edlothiad In a question asking whether the travel speeds make sense, isn't pointing out the problems with the travel speed the point?

Comment: Sure, but you're not really talking about the speed but instead her freezing. No matter what speed she flew at it would've been cold. The speed only makes it colder. She'd have frozen at any altitude at any speed.

Comment: Okay, another answer raised an interesting question. How did Dany found out exact location of the group? Any thoughts on that? Or did she just saw a black patch on white ice from above?

Comment: Probably the second. But we get no information on that. Although 100000 wights it's a snowy ice field with a fire sword is a pretty obvious sight in my opinion.

Comment: Now that I read this I'm not nearly as pissed about this episode as I was before... If they'd shown some montage/dialogue/... to show the passing of a couple of days that would have made an almost credible turn of events.

Comment: @fgysin there was some commentary where they discuss this to some extent, I think it was in the "inside this episode"

Answer (score 21):

- When Jon tells Gendry to leave it is still daylight out, and when he
  arrives it is night, and he is exhausted, so the most it took is a
  day, though he could also have started running at dusk and arrived
  early in the morning, so the lower limit will be his time of
  exhaustion (let's use median marathon times)
  **4 hours < Duration<sub>[G]</sub> < 23 hours**
- Using [this map](https://quartermaester.info/) and the scale they provide, I calculated the distance from Eastwatch to Dragonstone to be ~1,978.65 miles.
  Using [the wikipedia page on homing pigeons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homing_pigeon), I apply the same speed of 50mph to the Raven.
  Assuming the same raven could go the whole distance (multiple sources claim this to be impossible), and it could go that long without stopping, it would take 39.573 hours (or 1 day and 15 and a half hours). Some estimates say this distance could be as low as 1000 miles, because in the show Cersei says Winterfell is a thousand miles away (which is very similar to the distance from Dragonstone to Eastwatch), so let's use this as the lower limit.
  **20 hours < Duration<sub>[R]</sub> < 39.573 hours**
- The dragon's speed is where a lot of the guesswork and fantasy comes in, but we can reasonably assume that it will fly at least as fast as the raven (50mph), and that, because [D&D have compared them to F16 fighter jets](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X17pjukf8rA), using aeroplanes as a reference might not be too far outside the realm of reason, especially if we take the slowest plane as a reference, the [PZL M-15 Belphegor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PZL_M-15_Belphegor), which flies at 87-103mph.
  We will be using the same lower and upper bounds for the distance we used in the previous point.
  **9.71 hours < Duration<sub>[D]</sub> < 39.573 hours**
- This, in total, gives us the following estimated range for the
  Total duration of Gendry's run, the Raven's flight, and Drogon's flight:

  **33.71 hours < Duration<sub>[TOTAL]</sub> < 102.15 hours**

or

### at least 1 Day, 9 hours and 43 minutes

So, to answer your question:

> Was Daenerys' rescue achieved in a plausible time?

The show implies that part of a day and one full night passed after Gendry was sent - regardless of how you slice that, it's never gonna be enough time for Daenerys to get there on time, based on our estimated values, so **"No"** (a second night would have passed). The only way we can force this to be plausible is if we get things like faster dragon speeds (though it'd have to be accurate/canonical to a degree, I made a reasonable comparison to aeroplanes).

---

### Full disclosure notice

A lot of this is ***speculation*** because:

- **We don't know** how far the arrowhead mountain is from Eastwatch
- **We don't know** whether show distances are the same as book distances
- **We don't know** how fast a fictional raven or dragon flies

In conclusion, we know nothing, Jon Snow.

However: we do have enough information to make **an estimate** (rather than a guess) if we allow for a margin of error determined by the range of assumptions we make.

Comment: I think you're underestimating the speed at which dragons can fly, from canonical references to Targaryens flying long distances apparently quite casually and quickly.

Comment: @MikeScott It's better if you sent some numbers/pointed me in a direction slightly less vague than "canonical references". Greatly appreciated.

Comment: @GhotiandChips They're mentioned in a question linked in the comments to this question above: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/166108/54887

Comment: Think the dragon-speed estimate is reasonable, based on the battle scene two episodes before, where the dragon was easily able to cover the whole field and blow by the Dothraki in full horse-sprint in a matter of seconds.

Answer (score 19):

## It was supposed to be 'plausibly impossible'

### The horse's mouth

Recently, one of the show's directors, **[Alan Taylor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Taylor_(director))** - who was the actual director for the episode in question: *Beyond The Wall* - told *Variety*:

> We were aware that timing was getting a little hazy,... We’ve got Gendry running back, ravens flying a certain distance, dragons having to fly back a certain distance... In terms of the emotional experience, [Jon and company] sort of spent one dark night on the island in terms of storytelling moments. We tried to hedge it a little bit with the eternal twilight up there north of The Wall. I think there was some effort to fudge the timeline a little bit by not declaring exactly how long we were there. I think that worked for some people, for other people it didn’t. They seemed to be very concerned about how fast a raven can fly but there’s a thing called plausible impossibilities, which is what you try to achieve, rather than impossible plausibilities. So I think we were straining plausibility a little bit, but I hope the story’s momentum carries over some of that stuff.
> <sub>-Joe Otterson: [*‘Game of Thrones’ Director Alan Taylor Breaks Down Timeline in ‘Beyond the Wall’*](http://variety.com/2017/tv/news/game-of-thrones-season-7-episode-6-beyond-the-wall-timeline-director-1202534403), Variety.</sub>

### Time, distance and other irrelevant features of the universe

Taylor goes on to say that we shouldn't be so concerned about all of this, as they are trying to tell a story, and that story requires certain people to be in certain places at the right time; *how* they got there is not important to their timelines as '[the show goes on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rmp6zIr5y4U)':

> It’s cool that the show is so important to so many people that it’s being scrutinized so thoroughly,... If the show was struggling, I’d be worried about those concerns, but the show seems to be doing pretty well so it’s OK to have people with those concerns.
> <sub>-Joe Otterson: [*‘Game of Thrones’ Director Alan Taylor Breaks Down Timeline in ‘Beyond the Wall’*](http://variety.com/2017/tv/news/game-of-thrones-season-7-episode-6-beyond-the-wall-timeline-director-1202534403), Variety.</sub>

### In conclusion

Please don't think or try to calculate, simply *turn off your brain* and enjoy the dragons and boat-sex!

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not plausible. Presumably, Daenerys had already resolved to leave Dragonstone and head north to aid Jon Snow and his band long before the raven from the Wall arrived. It was pure coincidence that Daenerys happened to find Jon Snow and his band minutes before they were overwhelmed by the wights. I don't recall any explicit scenes or dialogue where we see Dany reading the message sent by the raven from the Wall.

Comment: She decides to fly back to rescue Jon based on knowing that he is in danger, against Tyrion's arguments that she might die. She says to Tyrion that she won't stay and "do nothing", so there's a heavy implication that she knows Jon is in danger.

Comment: @tobiasvl Right, she knows they're in danger because Jon Snow described the whole harebrained plan to her before he left. She doesn't want to stay and "do nothing". The other assumption is that Jon Snow is sent a raven asking for aid from Dany. Are we absolutely certain? Maybe the gist of the message was that the mission had failed.

Comment: Jon Snow seemed pretty certain that they were waiting for rescue. If they had no hope of rescue, I doubt they would have just stood around and waited to die. At the very least, they'd have done something to make sure they didn't become the newest recruits into the Night Kings army after they died.

Comment: @Shane You do have a point - if they were at wit's end (and frankly there's not much wit between Jon and the rest of that gang), why didn't they all decode to fight to the end? Or build a big fire and jump in it? I'd argue they hadn't yet reached that level of desperation where suicide was the only option left. We didn't hear Jon state "We just have to hold out for another 3 days for Dany to rescue us." You could argue that D&D wanted to leave viewers in the dark about whether Dany was coming to their rescue & how much time had passed, to make her appearance all the more unexpected.

Comment: @Shane I'm also skeptical the Night King would have waited for days or weeks until Jon & co. died of exposure or hunger. His army seemed to be waiting until the lake ice had refrozen, which it did overnight, then launched another attack (but more piecemeal to avoid cracking the ice).

Answer (score 4):

It's not plausible, given that Dany would have no means of navigating to where the magnificent seven were. Unless Dragons have GPS, it's utterly implausible that Dany could fly somewhere she's never been in her life, let alone find the exact geographical coordinates in the nick of time.

Comment: While you are not wrong, this does not add anything that the other answers have already addressed.

Comment: I disagree. The answers so far are considering whether it's possible for Dany's rescue mission to be achieved plausibly, assuming the shortest, fastest journey as the crow, or indeed dragon flies. My point is that it would be almost impossible for Dany to fly in a straight line, given she has only the vaguest inclination of which direction to point Drogon. Even assuming she was able to find the wall, and used that to navigate, she end up circling for hours trying to find Jon and co, if she was even able to spot them at all from the sky, given the weather. Therefore it's not plausible at all.

Comment: That's a fair point. Perhaps edit your answer to make that a bit more clear?

Comment: We don't know the contents of the note sent to Dany via Raven.  The party was more-or-less in the same spot when Gendry ran off and he could have described a compass direction plus distance in the note, getting Dany pretty close to the party.  Finally, amid the vast whiteness there was an army of moving bodies, perhaps 50,000 of them, covering a vast area which would have been visible from miles away.  And at the center of that were the seven living souls.

Answer (score 2):

The limiting factor here is the speed of the raven. We don't really know how far from the Wall they are, so Gendry's run could have taken a fairly short time, and we know that a dragon can fly much faster than a raven.

Ravens in our world aren't especially fast flyers, but these ravens have been bred for centuries as message carriers, so let's assume they can fly as fast as a homing pigeon, about 50 miles per hour. It's something like 2,000 miles from Eastwatch to Dragonstone, so that would be 40 hours for a non-stop raven. We can add an allowance of 5 hours for Gendry's run and 10 hours for Daenerys to fly back, so we're looking at a minimum of 55 hours, a bit over two days.

Comment: I'm thinking they're somewhere between Hardhome and Eastwatch-by-the-Sea, closer to the former than the latter — otherwise, if they were somewhere farther West, it's likely Jon would've sent Gendry running to Castle Balck instead.

Comment: I don't think that raven, nor homing pigeon, can fly during 40 hours without any rest

Comment: @JNat I seem to recall Jon explicitly told Gendry to run back to East Watch. So I believe it is unlikely that Jon told him to run to Castle Black. East watch is on Eastern end point of Wall, Castle Black is in the middle.

Comment: @Kepotx Homing pigeons can fly over 600 miles at 50mph. I don't think it's impossible to believe that a bigger and sturdier bird could manage the same over a longer distance. 50mph is an average speed; it could be 70mph while flying, with rest stops from time to time.

Comment: Huh... yeah, I know, @Aegon. I didn't say anything to contradict that. The author of the answer says "We don't really know how far from the Wall they are" and so I was just trying to help figure out where they might be: somewhere between Hardhome and Eastwatch, given that going further West would have put 'em closer to Castle Black instead, and thus Jon would have probably told Gendry to run there instead — is that clearer?

Comment: @JNat Indeed it is. And teaches me a thing or two about skimming comments. I just read the `it's likely Jon would've sent Gendry running to Castle Balck instead.` :D

Comment: At least it wasn't carrying a coconut.

Comment: @JNat It would probably be useless to tell Gendry to run to Castle Black, since he can't know where it is (remember that this is the first time he travels further North than the Riverlands). It's already surprising he was able to find Eastwatch.

Comment: @ArnaudD. It's not exactly hard to find Castle Black. "Run south until you hit the Wall. Then run west until you see Night's Watch on top of the Wall and a gate below them." But it's probably well over a hundred miles, so will take him several days at best.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Eastwatch is very easy to find. You just keep going South-East and you will eventually reach there. Shadow Tower is the same but in South-West. Castle Black is the tricky one, being in the middle and all. TLDR, it's not surprising that he found East Watch. He just had to keep going south East.

Comment: @MikeScott Would Gendry know that? Besides, there are 19 castles on the Wall, but most of them are abandoned. He could find several useless gates on his way. But I agree that Eastwatch would be easier, at least the general direction (and once he can see the Wall it's easy to follow it).

Comment: @ArnaudD. I'm pretty sure Jon Snow knows that (he does not, in fact, know nothing), and he could tell Gendry before sending him off. And the abandoned gates are why I said he should look for the one with Night's Watch on guard on the Wall above the gate.

Answer (score 2):

I like the discussion, but I think everyone is wrong about the distance. And that's a crucial part. It took 50 days for the Lannister party to arrive at Winterfell. And they didn't travel in straight lines. What's possible to travel in a day for such a big party with all stops etc, 20 miles a day? If so, we are talking 1000 miles. And that's not in straight lines. So perhaps 800 miles for a bird. Calculate on that and you get a different answer.

If the raven can fly at 50mph. The time for the raven is 16hours. If it took Gendry 5 hours (it could be less). We have 21 hours. The dragons are probably very fast. No idea how fast, but they are huge and from earlier it looks like Dany could move around pretty fast. Say they are 3x as fast or so, we have about 5 hours. In all 26hours. It's very likely that was about the time they were on that island.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it's plausible.

People don't die in a couple of days in those temperatures. You could tell me they were out there for a week, and I'd have no trouble believing they were still alive.

The only factor they have to deal with is water. They have fire on demand. So they have a semi reliable source of warmth. They have water as long as they keep breaking the ice open.

It would take weeks for them to become obviously diminished by lack of food.

Realistically, they were on the island for 4-5 days. Perfectly plausible.

Comment: Right, but in the span of one or two days, could Gendry have run back to Eastwatch, flown a raven to Dragonstone, and then Daenerys fly her dragons from Dragonstone all the way north of the wall? I think the way the TV series depicts elapsed time is out of whack.

Comment: @RobertF I like to think I've proven otherwise